# Restart loop when key value changes

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to create a loop that will print the group name and it's associated members on each loop.   In the following lines I would make the [key] the letter of the group and the [value] would be the name.

```
this is to set use my user group A user john
this is to set use my user group A user joe
this is to set use my user group B user mary
this is to set use my user group B user nancy
```

```
with open(file_in) as ip, open('file_group_script.txt', 'w') as panscript:
    print("config addrgrp")
        dup_groups = set()
        host = []
        members = {}
        for line in ip:
            key, value = line[7],line[9]
            lines = line.strip().split()
            if len(lines) > 9:
                if re.search('group', lines[6]):
                    if lines[7] not in dup_groups:
                        print(f'group name "{lines[7]}"')
                        dup_groups.add(lines[7])
                        members[line[7]] = line[9]
                        print(members)
```

It prints out the group name but then for the members all I get is:

```
group name A
{'u': 'i'}
{'u': 'i'}
group name B
{'u': 'i'}
{'u': 'i'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dup_groups` set is not needed and the field indexes were off by one.

Try this code:

```
ss = '''
this is to set use my user group A user john
this is to set use my user group A user joe
this is to set use my user group B user mary
this is to set use my user group B user nancy
'''.strip()

with open('test.dat','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write test file

####################################

import re

file_in = 'test.dat'

with open(file_in) as ip, open('file_group_script.txt', 'w') as panscript:
    host = []
    members = {}
    for line in ip:
        key, value = line[7],line[9]
        fields = line.strip().split()
        if len(fields) > 9:
            if re.search('group', fields[7]):
                if fields[8] in members.keys():  # if list exists
                    members[fields[8]].append(fields[10])  # append to list
                else:
                    members[fields[8]] = [fields[10]] # start list
                print(members)
                
print('\nFinal\n',members)
```

Output

```
{'A': ['john']}
{'A': ['john', 'joe']}
{'A': ['john', 'joe'], 'B': ['mary']}
{'A': ['john', 'joe'], 'B': ['mary', 'nancy']}

Final
 {'A': ['john', 'joe'], 'B': ['mary', 'nancy']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked great.  I follow everything you did except for this line:  members[fields[8]] = [fields[10]] - could you please explain that this does??

Comment: Answer updated. That line creates a new list based on the key.